# Visual Basic Easy Error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am making an MP3 player in Visual Basic.
I have made a "Recent Played", but I'm having a problem.

My "Recent Played" (`listbox1`) will only update when I do `Form1_Load`.
The same code won't work when I do `Label6_Click`.

Here is the line which loads recent songs into a list box:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = My.Settings.Recent
```

Here is the full code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ListBox1.DataSource = My.Settings.Recent
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Label5.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click
        If Label6.Text = "Play" Then
            My.Settings.Recent.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1.FileName))
            Call Update1()
            My.Settings.Save()
            WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Label5.Text
            WindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
            Label6.Text = "Pause"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        My.Settings.Recent.Clear()
        ListBox1.DataSource = My.Settings.Recent
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    End Sub

    Sub Update1()
        ListBox1.DataSource = My.Settings.Recent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your use of the `Call` keyword is superfluous. Also, I answered your previous question if you haven't seen that. :)

Comment: why not add them first to an Array, and when needed, add the new song to the Array as long as it doesn't already exist(made an `If` statement to find out) and then add the new items to the listbox

Comment: Thank you visual Vincent for my last question i found another way of fixing it but the call hasn't solved my issue and werdna do you understand my problem my listbox stays the same when i click label6 it should update with my line ListBox1.DataSource = My.Settings.Recent but it doesn't for some reason it updates when i load the form or relaunch the app

Comment: I never said removing call would work, but it is superfluous (unnecessary) to use in your case.

Comment: @Jeroen : `My.Settings.Save()` just updates/rewrites the settings file. The settings are still changed in memory.

Comment: @Jeroen : I've worked with `My.Settings` for a long time. Many times I've experienced the problem that the settings aren't saved after for example an application crash, just because I didn't call `My.Settings.Save()`. _However_ the settings were still changed before the crash, but (apparently) not written to the disk.

Comment: @Jeroen : Third possibility: There's something wrong with the data source method. -- My adviced for the OP: Debug your setting, either via breakpoints or by simply using `Console.WriteLine` or a `MessageBox`. See if it changes when it is supposed to.

Comment: @Jeroen : I hate to say this, but your theories are completely incorrect. First of all his method doesn't include any parameters, so this has nothing to do with `ByVal` nor `ByRef`. And it doesn't matter if he calls another method because it'd still be the same as doing it directly. Secondly a `ListBox` _is a reference type_ (a class) meaning you will always get it by reference.

Comment: @Jeroen : `you are accidentally updating a reference to the ListBox and not the thing itself` - Accessing something by reference means that you access _the object itself_ via a _**reference** pointing to **its location** in memory_ (meaning you will always access that specific object). Every time you access a class you are accessing it via its reference. -- Finally, the use of the `Call` keyword is just superfluous, it simply isn't needed. It doesn't change how the called method behaves. Infact it makes no difference if you use it or not, it'll behave the same either way.

Comment: The _recommended use_ of the `Call` keyword is when you are going to execute an expression that doesn't start with an identifier, for example this: `Call New BinaryFormatter().Serialize(myFileStream, Me)` - this reduces the need for extra variables. There are a few more examples on the [**MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz.aspx).

Comment: I have given 2 possible solutions that are being shot down for the sake of being shot down... So I deleted them. No point in discussing this issue with people hell bend on arguing rather than practically testing possibilities

Comment: @Jeroen : Please don't take my responses so personally. If you felt that I did this for the sake of simply being patronizing (or antagonizing), then I'm sorry for not writing my comments in a more friendly manner. It is sometimes hard for me to express myself in a nice, friendly way while trying to explain something of (at least a little bit of) importance. -- I never disliked your potential solutions nor your will to help (because sometimes it is those small things that matter), but I just wanted to explain why they _shouldn't_ work due to how, or how they appear, to work.

Comment: @Jeroen : And now you taught me a lesson :). In the future I'll think even more carefully about how I write my comments/responses.